# How do I use exec() with input args?

Tags: go

How can I use exec with multiple argument in go? I've found an example of exec in go, but i don't understand how to use multiple args, this is what i've tried:

```
cmdName := os.Args[1]

cmdArgs := []string{os.Args[1:]}

cmd := exec.Command(cmdName, cmdArgs...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to use [`exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) with multiple arguments:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", args)

    res, err := exec.Command("ls", args...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", string(res))
}
```

Without args:

```
echo -e $(go run args.go )
[] "args.go
file1
file2
file3
"
```

With `-s` and `-r` args:

```
echo -e $(go run args.go -s -r )
[-s -r] "total 4
0 file3
0 file2
0 file1
4 args.go
"
```